# How to execute complicated Parse or Express promise pattern

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, promise

I have code of the following pattern in express using Parse Queries:

```
var function1 = function(a){
     if(a){
        var setSomething = new Parse.Object
        setSomething.set("thing", "stuff");
        setSomething.save();
     }else{
        var query = new Parse.Query(Shortcut);
        query.first({
            success: function(getThing){
               getThing.set("thing", "otherStuff");
               getThing.save();
               }
         })
      }
   }

var function2 = function(){
    var a = true;
    function1(a)
}()

var function3 = function(){
    var a = false;
    function1(a)
}()
```

I'd like to use promises to do all of the saves at once and then res.send back to my front end but I can't figure out the pattern and whether I should be using Parse promises or some other promise library and if I am using Parse promises if it is Parse.Promise() or Parse.Promise.as() and either way if I'm pushing to arrays or calling the 'when' method and then where I should be calling the when method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe this works but it look like it does!
I based my answer off this post:
[Parse Cloud Code: How to Invoke Promises for Async Saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416123/parse-cloud-code-how-to-invoke-promises-for-async-saving?rq=1)

```
var function1 = function(a){
     if(a){
        var setSomething = new Parse.Object
        setSomething.set("thing", "stuff");
        return setSomething.save();
     }else{
        var query = new Parse.Query(Shortcut);
        query.first({
            success: function(getThing){
               getThing.set("thing", "otherStuff");
               return getThing.save();
               }
         })
      }
   }

var function2 = function(){
    var a = true;
    return function1(a)
}()

var function3 = function(){
    var a = false;
    return function1(a)
}()

Parse.Promise.when(function2(), function3())
.then(function(){
      res.send("Success")})
```

Key point to notice for the newbie: I return all of the inner functions and the save functions in function1 also.